# BigDecimal serialization with unknown scale and precision

Tags: kotlin, avro, avro4s

I am trying to serialize a data class using Avro4k.

```
@Serializable
class Aggregator(
    @ScalePrecision(10, 10)
    @Serializable(with = BigDecimalSerializer::class)
    val value: BigDecimal
)
```

The problem is that I don't know the scale and precision of the BigDecimal beforehand, and I get rounding errors if they are not big enough.

Is there a way to not inform the scale and precision, and use whatever values the provided object have? I don't know if Avro / Avro4k would support that.

Comment: Without some specifics, this looks like premature optimisation to me. It's also difficult to answer, because there's not enough information to determine what would be good enough. What values could there be? What numbers would be 'huge'? What performance would be good enough, or unacceptable? Have you tried any solutions? What problems have you encountered? Do you have control over both the encoding and decoding, or do you have to conform to a 'public' spec?

Comment: What I would really like to do is not have to inform the scale and precision, and use the ones in each object instead. I might end up using a String converting to BigDecimal manually later then.

Comment: Sorry if this is too obvious, but have you tried simply omitting the `@Scale` annotation?

Comment: Yep. Then a default scale and precision is used, which does not suit me.

Comment: Regarding performance, BigDecimal proved way more compact, so I have to use it. Using a very high scale and precision threw weird errors during deserialization, so I used 25 and 12, and hopefully I won't receive any data requiring more than data, which also throws Exception from Avro4k library during producing (because it doesn't know how to round it). I wish there was a way to have Avro4k use the actual scale and precision from each object it's serializing, but I don't know if that is supported or even makes sense from Avro point of view.